# Enable/Disable Reactive Commands with Delay

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

Am working on simple turn based game using WPF and ReactiveUI? I am very new to Reactive UI/Reactive Extensions.

On a particular View, I have 3 buttons, say "Kick", "Punch", "Run Away".

On clicking any of these buttons, It will call either, the Kick, Punch or RunAway functions of the Fight Class, all of which return a string, which I display on the view.

```
this.KickCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateCommand();
this.KickCommand.Subscribe(x => 
    {
        this.Message = this.Fight.Kick();
    });
```

Similarly, I have remaining Commands.

I would like to do the following.

When a Command is triggered I want all the commands to be disabled for duration of 2 seconds, while the message is being displayed and then after two seconds the message is cleared out and the command are enabled again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one way to do it, with comments:

```
        var canExecute = new Subject<bool>();
        KickCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(canExecute);
        PunchCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(canExecute);
        RunAwayCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(canExecute);
        new[] { KickCommand, PunchCommand, RunAwayCommand }.Select(cmd => {
            // skip the initial false, we don't want to delay that one
            var isExec = cmd.IsExecuting.Skip(1);
            // delay re-activation (falses) by 2s
            return new[] { isExec.Where(x => x), isExec.Where(x => !x).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) }.Merge()
            // add back an initial false
            .StartWith(false);
        })
            // all commands needs to be in this non-executing-since-2s state
            .CombineLatest(l => l.All(x => !x))
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Do(ClearMessageIfTrue)
            .Subscribe(canExecute);
```

I skipped the command subscribe parts as you seem to already have that one.